# How do URLs work in a country with non-latin chars?

Tags: internationalization

How do URLs work in other countries? Let's say India or China that use non A-Z characters.

Do they use English terms in the URL? Or can they write characters in urls like:

> सच्चाई.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the context and characters used.

**Domain names**

Domain names that use non-ASCII characters are known as [Internationalized Domain Names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) (IDNs). They are encoded using [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) into the ASCII character set. This is to maintain compatibility with older networking software that doesn't understand Unicode.

For example, I have registered a domain name with a letter containing an 'umlaut' character. Here, **`übersolve.com`** which translates to **`XN--BERSOLVE-55A.COM`** in DNS.

**Filenames / query strings**

In most cases, non-ASCII characters in filenames can be represented by Unicode.

However some characters aren't allowed in URLs at all. These are [percent-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). For example a space character ' ' would be replaced with **`%20`**.

Comment: Do you have real example of china/india/whatever use in url ?

Comment: @yes123: http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/idna-examples.html

Comment: Isn't the percent encoding just for after the domain (i.e. after the /)?

Comment: @paulmorriss: Yes - that's why I put it under the 'filenames / query strings' heading. Do you think I should make that clearer?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't spot that heading. Maybe it you add "(the bit after the slash)".